# Running NodeJS worker in Docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, heroku, docker-compose

I have an application that looks like this one:
https://github.com/heroku-examples/node-workers-example

In short, I have 2 processes:

1. **Server**: it server US, handles requests and adds them to Redis
2. **Worker**: it pulls requests from Redis and works on them

Should I use only one Docker image for both processes or should I have 2 docker images (one for the server and the second for the worker)? What is the best practice?

I personally think, it's better to have 2 images. In this case, can my project structure be like this one:

```
Project Folder
-node_modules
-utils
-server.js
-package.json
-Dockerfile
-docker-compose.yml
-/worker
-/worker/index.js
-/worker/Dockerfile
```

Is there any advice?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: this is very opinionated response, but author is asking for an opinion.*

You can do one or two but it all depends on how you wanna schedule it.

If you want to stay flexible in the amount of processes you want for each I would go with two docker images otherwise you'll need to each time spin a fixed amount of each or you'll need to tweak that setting via env variables or via other means...

Hence one for the frontend part and one for the background process.

As you are having two different images, I usually prefer to separate that in two distincts projects but that's a matter of taste. Even though because of how NodeJS manages dependencies (`node_modules`) it's easier to have 2 distincts folders when the dependencies are very different.

I would go with following:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── front
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   └── src
│       └── main.js
└── worker
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── node_modules
    ├── package.json
    └── src
        └── main.js
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the opinion! The dependencies are pretty the same, so I wouldn't like to use 2 separate folders for this project.

Comment: I think for this project I will use only one container, it's very basic and I won't need any flexibility here. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Obviously there are a lot of factors to take into account when thinking about how to structure your project. If I answered your question please consider validating it.